# converting char array to upper case and use toUpperCase

Tags: java

I want to make a program in java that takes a string as input and displays the same string with alternate positions of each character uppercase and lower case.

Comment: And your question is? If it's "Could you make this for me?", the answer is no, that's not what this site is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site might not be for having people make things for you, but I was happy to make it. I enjoy little random exercises to keep my brain active.

Here is a working solution based on RuntimeException's suggestion:

```
public class UpperAndLower {
    private static String convertString(String input) {
        String output = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0)     // checks if the character is even
                output = output + input.substring(i, i+1).toUpperCase();
            else
                output = output + input.substring(i, i+1).toLowerCase();
        }

        return output;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(convertString("Hello World"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint - Alternate position means an if condition to check whether your array index is odd or even. For even index, change to upperCase. For odd index, change to lower case. 
It will be easier if you convert your string into an array of substrings (substring having length 1), instead of converting to char array.

Try it out, and post your code if you face any further problems.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the entire string to upper case then you can either change the chars at even index to lower or chars at odd index to lower.  OR
2. Change the entire string to lower case then you can either change the chars at even index to upper or chars at odd index to upper.